# How to set a lifetime of a bearer token while retrieving through Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, authorization

I use the following command in Powershell to get a bearer token:

```
az account get-access-token --output json -s <subscription-id> --resource https://management.azure.com/
```

It works well but the token I get always expires in an hour. Is there a way to manually set the expiry time?

Answer (score 2):

When a client acquires an access token to access a protected resource, the client also receives a refresh token. The refresh token is used to obtain new access/refresh token pairs when the current access token expires. A refresh token is bound to a combination of user and client. A refresh token can be [revoked at any time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#token-revocation), and the token's validity is checked every time the token is used. Refresh tokens are not revoked when used to fetch new access tokens - it's best practice, however, to securely delete the old token when getting a new one.

It's important to make a distinction between confidential clients and public clients, as this impacts how long refresh tokens can be used. For more information about different types of clients, see RFC [6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1).

You can read more about it in below doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Additionally there is a different way to maintain token lifetime, you can check in the below blog:

https://mikhail.io/2019/07/how-azure-cli-manages-access-tokens/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there just no way to specify somewhere in this powershell command an expiry time? (as one of the parameters) Information you gave me, whilst being useful, seems overly complicated.

Comment: Shouldn't be complicated...AFAIK this seems the right way of fetching token.